# Constraints not changing in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nslayoutconstraint

I have created an app, in which i have a `tableview`. I want to move the `view` in certain conditions so I have changed the constraints, its working fine but when i tried to change the constraints again, the `view` is not moved.

My code as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"GoalDetailsCustomCardCell" bundle:nil];

[goalDetailsTableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CardCell"];
GoalDetailsTableViewCell *cell = [goalDetailsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CardCell"];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [goalDetailsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CardCell"];
}

if([self.swipedRowArray containsObject:indexPath])
        {
            NSLog(@"%f", cell.cardDetails.frame.origin.x);
            NSLog(@"%f", cell.cardDetails.frame.size.width);
            NSLog(@"%f", cell.cardDetails.frame.size.height);

            cell.cardDetails.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            NSDictionary *contentDictionary = @{@"cardDetails":cell.cardDetails, @"actionReminderCard":cell.actionCardReminder};
            [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(-314)-[cardDetails]" options:0 metrics:nil views:contentDictionary]];
            [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-8-[actionReminderCard]" options:0 metrics:nil views:contentDictionary]];
            NSLog(@"%f", cell.cardDetails.frame.size.width);
            NSLog(@"%f", cell.cardDetails.frame.size.height);
        }

else
{

            NSLog(@"%f", cell.cardDetails.frame.origin.x);
            NSLog(@"%f", cell.cardDetails.frame.size.width);
            NSLog(@"%f", cell.cardDetails.frame.size.height);

            cell.cardDetails.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            NSDictionary *contentDictionary = @{@"cardDetails":cell.cardDetails, @"actionReminderCard":cell.actionCardReminder};
            [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-8-[cardDetails]" options:0 metrics:nil views:contentDictionary]];
            [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-330-[actionReminderCard]" options:0 metrics:nil views:contentDictionary]];
            NSLog(@"%f", cell.cardDetails.frame.size.width);
            NSLog(@"%f", cell.cardDetails.frame.size.height);
        }
```

In the above code, if part is working perfectly, when it comes to else i tried to change the constraints to default constraints as set in the `xib` but it is not working. It shows the view as same as I changed the constraints before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to update the new constraints again

Comment: @S R Nayak - Can u please help me how to get into old constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are adding constraint. it will not remove when you add new constraint. so you should delete those constraint and add new constraint or you should update same constraint. you can do this in two ways.

using programatically first remove all constraint and then add new constraint. same as @Tejvansh Singh Chhabra's answer. *but make sure it will remove all your contentview's constraint.*

```
[cell.contentView removeConstraints:cell.contentView.constraints];
```

The Other option is take outlet of `NSLayoutConstraint`X position and then update it. but i think for that you should add all your contentview's subviews to UIView and then bind Leading constraint to your outlet and just change `cell.yourConstraint.constant = yourvalue` in your if-else condition.

take one outlet in your customcell

```
IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraint_xPosition;
```

then outlet it as i shown in below image.

[image]

and in if-else condition change constant like `cell.constraint_xPosition.constant = 0;//-320`

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: Can u please tell me the second way as you specified like outlet of `NSLayoutConstraint`. Can u please provide me some code example for this

Comment: May i know It should be added in .h or .m file?

Comment: @Balaji in customcell.h and bind it in xib.

Comment: But if add this outlet in customcell.h. I could not able to get this outlet in `cellFOrRowAtIndexPath` if else conditon.

Comment: @Balaji have you added `cell.constraint_xPosition.constant = yourvalue`? same way you are accesing `cell.cardDetails`

Comment: what is `yourConstraint` in this expression

Comment: yes.. Thats what I am telling i have added IBOutlet in customcell.h but when i tried to set values for it from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in `tableViewController` its showing error Property constraint_xPosition.constant not found. Replace ". with ->"

Comment: @Balaji you have to add property `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraint_xPosition;` otherwise you will not access it in your class.

Comment: Actually i have initialized a new cell for each row.. Anyway thanks for your help... Eventhough i did not used your answer, ur answer is correct. So +1 and correct. :). May i know ur facebook id and mail id..

Answer (score 1):

You need to first remove your old constraints before adding new constraints to cell maybe thats what causing issue. After removing all constraints you need to add all constraints again programmatically.

```
[cell.contentView removeConstraints:cell.contentView.constraints];
```